# How to bind data to listbox using its ItemTemplate property?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

Can anyone tell me how to bind data to listbox.

```
          listbox_mypet.ItemsSource = pg_addPet.list_listMyPet;
```

My class is

```
    public class SaveMypet
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Birthday { get; set; }
    public string FavFood { get; set; }
    public string DocNo { get; set; }
    public string VacDate { get; set; }
    public string FavToy { get; set; }
   // public ImageSource  Image1 { get; set; }

}
```

My code is not working

```
          <ListBox Foreground="Black" FontSize="24" Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top="80" Height="313" Name="listbox_mypet" Width="415" Margin="20,80,-435,-393">

                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"> </TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Birthday}"> </TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FavFood}"> </TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DocNo}"> </TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding VacDate}"> </TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FavToy}"> </TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>
```

It displays System.Windows.Controls.TextBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have done so far is excellent. But i am thinking that you might have gone wrong in adding the data to the list.Here is my suggestion.

```
List<SaveMyPet> source=new List<SaveMyPet>();
source.Add(new SaveMyPet(Name="Dumpy", Birthday="21/3/2012", FavFood="Bone:,DocNo="23",VacDate="21/3/2013",FavToy="Bone"));

listbox_mypet.DataContext=this;
listbox_mypet.ItemSource=source;
```

You can add as many as SaveMyPet items to the list and add it to the source finally. ObservableCollection also works fine. Doubts over this, comment it!

Comment: Thanks...but actualy I am storing SaveMyPet class object data in list. That list again stored into isolated storage object And then I retrieve that object and cast to list and I want to bind list to listbox....But I am unable to show data...It display    {   System.Windows.Controls.TextBox   }  instead of actual value

Comment: are you getting the listboxitems as many as your item is list ?

Comment: problem solved thanks..   solution I have tried is textbox.text

Answer (score 0):

do this in your page.xaml.cs ..

```
 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        lstSaveMypet = new ObservableCollection<SaveMypet>();
        SaveMypet objsaveMypet = new SaveMypet();
        objsaveMypet.Birthday = "birthday1";
        objsaveMypet.DocNo = "asdklfj";
        objsaveMypet.FavFood = "pizza";
        objsaveMypet.Name = "tom";
        objsaveMypet.VacDate = "asfhak";
        objsaveMypet.FavToy = "ajdfhk";

        lstSaveMypet.Add(objsaveMypet);
        lstSaveMypet.Add(objsaveMypet);
        lstSaveMypet.Add(objsaveMypet);
        lstSaveMypet.Add(objsaveMypet);
        lstSaveMypet.Add(objsaveMypet);

        listbox_mypet.ItemsSource = lstSaveMypet;
        this.DataContext = this;


    }

    private ObservableCollection<SaveMypet> _lstSaveMypet;
    public ObservableCollection<SaveMypet> lstSaveMypet
    {
        get
        {
            return _lstSaveMypet;
        }
        set
        {
            _lstSaveMypet = value;

        }
    }
```

here i have use dummy data.

Comment: in your Pagexaml.cs in whose xaml you have defined your listbox. or just wait for 5 min i will come with some working code